# SQL and Joining in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Suppose I have two tables in SQL Server one is `Emp` and another is `FieldsInfo`.

`Emp` table looks with data like below

[image]

`FieldsInfo` table looks with data like below

[image]

Now I want to join both the tables in such a way that SQL Server would show data from `Emp` table but field name will be shown from `FieldsInfo` table according to the relation.

I mean `Employee ID` will be shown as Field name instead of ID and `Salary` will be shown as field name instead of Sal but value will be just like `Emp` table.

I am not able to generate this type of output after joining. So please help with right SQL script.

thanks

Comment: I would suggest that your design is bad. Name the fields what you want them to be named and get rid of the fields info tables altogether. Otherwise all your queries will be in dynamic sql which is difficult to write well and horrible to properly test. This is a lose lose situation, Fix it at the table level. (and never name an ID field ID!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your FieldsInfo table to build the SQL statement dynamically.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(100)
set @SQL = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + FieldName + ' as [' + Description + '], '
from FieldsInfo
where TableName = 'Emp'

set @SQL = 'select '+ left(@SQL, len(@SQL)-1) + ' from Emp'

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 1):

From how I understand your question what you're trying to achieve is not possible because you needed a dynamic AS clause which is unsupported.

Example:

```
SELECT EmpName AS *(SELECT TOP 1 Description FROM FieldsInfo WHERE FieldName = 'EmpName')*
FROM Emp
```

I guess you should try to do the mapping in whatever application the results are actually used. If you need the output in SQL Server I'm not sure if temp tables will do the trick.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(100)
set @SQL = ''
select @SQL =  stuff((select ', ' + [FieldName] + ' as ['+ [Description] +']'
                  from FieldsInfo t2 
                  where t2.TableName = t1.TableName 
                  for xml path('')),1,1,'') 
    from FieldsInfo t1
    group by TableName   

set @SQL = 'select '+ @SQL + ' from Emp'

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to use a table for field names, as you would be adding an extra layer of complexity.

```
SELECT 
    ID [Employee ID], 
    EmpName [Employee Name], 
    Sal [Salary] 
FROM 
    Emp
```